# Interval of monotonicity of $ f(x) = \frac{|x-1|}{x^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$ f(x) = \frac{|x-1|}{x^{2}}\ \ $ Opening this function we have

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1-x}{x^{2}} &, x< 1\\
 \frac{x-1}{x^{2}}&, x>1\
\end{cases}
$$

Afterwards we take the derivative we get

$$
f'(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{x-2}{x^{3}} &, x< 1\\
 \frac{2-x}{x^{3}}&, x>1\
\end{cases}
$$

the question asked for the interval where the function is increasing and decreasing. We already know that If the $f(x)$ is increasing then $f'(x) > 0$ and if decreasing then $f'(x) <0$. I don't know how to figure out the interval from here though.

Comment: Have you learned how to solve the inequality $\frac{x-2}{x^3} > 0$?

Comment: @Trebor Why particularly $(x-2)/x^{3}$

Comment: @RiRi there is no particular reason. It just happens that I chose this from the two relevant expressions.

Comment: @Paulo Do you mean that because $x^2$ is positive, then the function has the same intervals of monotonicity as $|x-1|$ ? This is not true.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe You are right. I thought about something else (when the function is positive/negative), but it doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
$\space f'(x)=\cases{\frac{x-2}{x^3}, \space x<1\\
\frac{2-x}{x^3}, \space x>1}$

$f'(x) > 0?$

$f'(x) > 0 \iff \cases{\frac{x-2}{x^3}>0 \space \land \space x<1\\
\frac{2-x}{x^3}>0 \space \land \space x>1} \iff \cases{x>2 \space \land \space x<0 \space \land \space x<1\\
0<x<2 \space \land \space x>1}\\ \iff\cases{x<0\\ 1<x<2}\iff\boxed{x\in(-\infty, 0) \cup (1, 2)}.$

Comment: What is the inverted V btw?

Comment: It is logical and...